# How do I add a random offset to values in a Pseq?

Tags: supercollider

Given a `Pseq` similar to the following:

```
Pseq([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], inf)
```

How would I randomise the values slightly each time? That is, not just randomly alter the 8 values once at initialisation time, but have a random offset added each time a value is sent to the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat way:

```
(Pseq([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], inf) + Pgauss(0, 0.1))
```

First you need to know that `Pgauss` is just a pattern that generates gaussian random numbers. You can use any other kind of pattern such as `Pwhite`.

Then you need to know the really pleasant bit: performing basic math operations on Patterns (as above) composes the patterns (by wrapping them in `Pbinop`).

Comment: Oh, you put the random function *outside* the `Pseq` call. I would never have guessed that. Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29